# Docker-compose - Docker at the startup

Tags: docker, dockerfile, laradock

I'm starting with Docker and Laravel. I've cloned the Laradock images from GitHub. The services are running fine with this command: (from into the path of Laradock)

```
#docker-compose up -d apache2 gitlab
```

The problem is in the startop of the OS. The containers doesn't running.

I've read from the ofical documentation of Docker and there is the command:

```
#docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped laravel_apache2
#docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped laravel_gitlab
```

I'm not sure why when I've restarted the machine the services are running(docker ps) but I haven't access to the server by apache2 and Gitlab.

If it is execute again the first commmand from the path:

```
#docker-compose up -d apache2 gitlab
```

It's working fine again.

I'm sure that the problem is between docker and docker-compose I don't know how to put in the startup the containers running by docker-compose command.

Should be I have build a container and move or config by different way :(

Please Could you help me to put in the startup a containers running by docker-compose?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think your containers aren’t starting up?  If you remove the `-d` option, is there any interesting output?  Can you update this question to include the `docker-compose.yml` file you’re trying to run and the text of any error messages you’re getting (both as text, not images, and inline in the question, not behind links)?

Comment: The containers are running correctly using the command docker-compose up -d container_name. I want to run on the startup the containers without using the command. If I use the docker run command running the container without the configuration.

Comment: If you specify any non-default options at all in your `docker-compose.yml`, or if you depend on inter-container networking at all, a plain `docker run` command won’t reproduce those; it doesn’t look at the `docker-compose.yml` file at all.

Comment: Mmmmm, ok, then How to run the docker-compose environment into the startup?

Comment: Just running `docker-compose up` should do it; is there a reason you’re trying to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make this behavior permanent, is to modify the docker-compose.yml, by adding the following line to each service that you need the OS to restart upon startup: `restart: unless-stopped`

Once you saved the modified docker-compose.yml file, you'll need to restart your services, example:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d apache2 gitlab
```